# MySQL query search with 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I have a 
vehicle (vin, vmaker, vmodel, vyear) 
         customer (SSN, cname, cgender, ccity)
         buyvehicle (BVSSN, BVVin, price, year)

I need a query that finds the vehicle with the highest sale price for each maker.

Please help!

example:
Honda Civic $20000 
Honda Accord $25000 
BMW 3 Series $22000 
BMW 5 Series $40000

the result should be: 
 
Honda Accord 
BMW 5 Series

Comment: are you looking for the vehicle with the greatest price or the vehicle with the most sales? please post some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: I am looking for the vehicle with highest price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the vehicle with the highest price you should be able to use something like this:

```
select v.vmaker, max(b.price) price
from vehicle v
left join buyvehicle b
    on v.vin = b.bvvin
group by v.vmaker
```